# Windows 10 IoT and other OSes on NOOBS install list

Tags: noobs

Can I install Windows 10 IoT on PI 3, and also retain NOOBS install list?

If I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>, NOOBS seems to be missing. These is no option to install another distro.

Answer (score -1):

Problem went away just now!  Must be a question of timing!
Thanks to anyone who might have seen this original post and thought of an answer.